# How to transform object of key - value pairs into array of objects with a single pair JS in a clean way

Tags: javascript

Basically I have an enum describing status

```
status = {1: "new", 2: "working" ... }
```

and I need to take it from that to something like

```
status = [{1: "new"}, {2: "working"} ...]
```

in a clean way ... i.e.

something readable, (maybe) simple and reliable. Currently I am not sure how to go about this ... maybe go through the object and "map" each pair to a brand new object in an array? Sounds bad.

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))`
The result of the map is the array, what you want.
Or:

```js
const arrayData = [];
for (const key in data) {
  arrayData.push({[key]: data[key]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate on objects dynamicly:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const { object } = require("prop-types")

const status = { 1: "new", 2: "working" }

const statusUpdate = Object.entries(status).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))

console.log(statusUpdate);